# App crash in the second launch time in a real device when i use LocationManager.getLastKnowLocation()

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, okhttp

When I run the code below in a emulator, it works totally fine. But when I run it in a real device, it keeps crashing and it can rarely work(Almost all the time it works the first time it launched when I reinstalled).But when i omit lines of code that relate to location, it works fine.(I indicate them with a `//**` every line). I have just learn Android development for 1 month so i made a lot of mistakes. Now I really need to get the latitude and longitude of the current location. Pls help me).By the way the real device is Redmi 8 Android 9

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GetCityName = findViewById(R.id.get_city_name);
    CityName = findViewById(R.id.city_name);
    temperature = findViewById(R.id.temperature);
    //**if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, PERMISSION_STRING) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        //**ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{PERMISSION_STRING}, 6699);
    //**}

    //**final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //**final String Gps_provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
    //**final Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(Gps_provider);
    GetCityName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //*String longgg = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            //*String lattt = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
           api_key(lattt,longgg);


        }
    });
}//get the weather data with current latitude and longtitude
private void api_key(String Lat,String Longg) {
    OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();

    Request request=new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+Lat+"&lon="+Longg+"&appid=a6f41d947e0542a26580bcd5c3fb90ef&units=metric")
            .get()
            .build();
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        Response response= client.newCall(request).execute();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                String responseData= response.body().string();
                try {
                    JSONObject json=new JSONObject(responseData);
                    String name = json.getString("name");
                    JSONObject temp1= json.getJSONObject("main");
                    String Temperature=String.valueOf(temp1.getDouble("temp"));


                    setText(CityName,name);
                    setText(temperature, Temperature);





                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}//This simply use to set text to TextView
private void setText(final TextView text, final String value){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(value);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The `getLastKnownLocation()` may well return null. An Android device does not automatically track its location all the time. The _"last known location"_ is available only if some application has requested the location. So you should not expect to always get a location with `getLastKnownLocation()`. And even if it returns something the location might not be up-to-date anymore. You should request location updates to get up-to-date data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ask for location permission in your code? I think you are missing those and this will be the only reason to crash on actual device. check out this link
if you follow this I'm sure you'll get your problem fixed

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

Comment: i already have  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> in AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You must have to ask user prompt for location permission before you call the location manager, defining permission in the manifest is just a way to tell the Android system that I need the location permission but you need to ask for that through java code once.